# Make all new chrome Windows incognito

Tags: chrome-for-android, privacy

Is there a way to make all new Google chrome Windows on my Android be in incognito mode? Thank you!

Comment: Might help: [How can I automatically clear my browsing data when I exit Chrome?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/117496/96277)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For android you need to have your phone rooted. Then you can go ahead and install IncognitoTab in xposed modules and it will work. If you want private browsing without root then download another browser like dolphin or Firefox.

Comment: Refer to this website: http://www.howtogeek.com/137466/how-to-always-start-any-browser-in-private-browsing-mode/ I think it explains it better then I can.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, 
it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here 
and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Ok but the answer you stated said for Windows. For android you need to have your phone rooted. Then you can go ahead and install IncognitoTab in xposed modules and it will work. If you want private browsing without root then download another browser like dolphin or Firefox.