# How can I automatically clear my chrome browsing data with tasker

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, tasker

i followed these instructions,

[How can I automatically clear my browsing data when I exit Chrome?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117496/how-can-i-automatically-clear-my-browsing-data-when-i-exit-chrome/)

and works very well on android 6.0.1

I tried on other android 4.1.2 devices, but tasker give me a 255 error?

Are there limitations on android 4.1.2??

Have you any idea??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the scripts and they work pretty well on android 4.3.

However to diagnose your problem I made 2 tests:

1. Ran the script in Tasker without root - the result was indeed a 255 error see below:

[image: error 255]

2. Disabled root and enabled Tasker's acessibilty service - the script is executed normally.

So in conclusion, you need to **Enable accessibility service** for Tasker or tick use root, however root is not a necessity as long you've enabled the accessibilty of Tasker.

So you just need to follow the [Instructions for Tasker](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/117531/209414) and perform the script mentioned by [Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/117531/209414) ,  (credit  to Firelord):

Comment: It didn't work for me, I tried using the above script u mentioned but didn't worked out and also Tasker doesn't produce any errors, still I check on chrome and saw the browsing data